# how to redirect to specific component in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to redirect inside a URL without page refresh, without using a router link as below :

```html
<router-link to="/about us " active-class="active">foo</router-link>
```

I want to print routes like below:

```html
<li class="nav-item phone">
    <a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html">
        اتصل بنا
    </a>
</li>
```

My route:

```js
const routes = [
    { path: '/aboutus/', component: AboutUs }
]
```

Comment: Use `router-link`, it generates an `a` tag anyway.  You can't link to an actual file like `contact-us.html` without refreshing.  You could maybe use an iFrame?  If you want a multi-page app for SEO purposes, use Nuxt/SSR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
this.$router.push('about')
```

Comment: It depends on where you want to redirect the page. for example if you put this code in **created** lifecycle of your component, it redirects the page as when the component loads.

Comment: It is a **javascript** code. put this where you want

Answer (score 0):

You may need a workaround for this.

This solution won't change the `url` either :)

Set an `html` in the data

```
    data: () => {
        return {
            html: null
        }
    }
```

Get the content of your `html` file using any request and assign to the `html` in `data` section. You can fetch this from any life cycle hook. Here I'm using `beforeMount`.

```
    beforeMount() {
        this.fetchAllEmployees();
        axios.get('contact-us.html')
            .then(response => {
                this.html = response.data;
            })
    }
```

Now you can show the `html` content in your component like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-html="html"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

To show only when clicking the `a` tag, you can add another variable in the `data` which can be used to toggle the value.